# CSS: It is possible to remove all padding and spacing, below 0 pixels?

Tags: html, css

I've put a new image in my table cells and it's making the table a bit bulky. I've reduced all padding and spacing to 0, but there are still gaps of about 4 pixels around the edge of the images (32 pixel rectangular flags). It is possible to remove all white space from a table cell?

My CSS for the cells is :

```
.flag {
    margin: 0px !important;
    padding: 0px !important;
    border-spacing:0 !important;
    height:28px !important;
    width:32px !important;
    line-height:32px !important;
}
```

Note that they need '!important' because they're over-riding another CSS. The exact height of the flags appears to be 28px. If I reduce height below that, the flag starts to get shaved off at the bottom of the cell.

More info so people can try for themselves.

```css
td { border: 1px solid black; }
```

```html
    <link
    rel="stylesheet"
    type="text/css"
    href="//cloud.github.com/downloads/lafeber/world-flags-sprite/flags32.css"
    />

    <table class = 'f32'><tr><td class = 'flag us'></td></tr></table>
```

Make sure your table has visible borders and you'll see that there's a fair bit of spacing above and below the flag image. I want to get rid of that, or preferably all except 1 pixel above and below.

Comment: Could the whitespace be on the actual image file? And it sounds weird, but sometimes removing the actual whitespace between the html elements does the trick.

Comment: It could be, but unfortunately that's out of my control because I'm importing the images. Not quite sure how to check. If it's that, would it not be possible to force the cell to be a certain height anyway and then somehow centre the flag in the cell? When I try that, it just pushes it downwards are partially out of the cell.

Comment: Welp. Couldn't exactly say without some experimentation, afraid I'm not going to be of much for assistance. Hope you find your answer though!

Comment: we'd need some more code (HTML, more CSS) and possibly a codepen or JSfiddle to check...

Comment: Editted, you should be able to replicate it with just those couple of lines in a new html file. Sorry, don't know how to do a JSfiddle yet, I'll have a look into it.

Comment: I've added a "Stack Snippet" which is like jsfiddle, but built into Stack Overflow's editor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends if the white space is all around the images or only below them.

Try to add `vertical-align:baseline;` to your CSS rule for the cells - this should at least eliminate unwanted space below the image.

If there is whitespace within the image itself, you might try negative margin values on the images, like

```
.flag img { 
  margin-top: -4px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The whitespace is within the image itself, and it's using a "sprite", wherein there are multiple images and a `background-position` is set such that the appropriate icon is displayed.

I've replicated what I think you want below. Note that I've overridden the styles without the use of `!important`. You just need the selector to be more specific than the one you're overriding.

```css
.f32 td.flag.us {
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 23px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-position: 0 -7332px;
  width: 30px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cloud.github.com/downloads/lafeber/world-flags-sprite/flags32.css" />

<table class='f32'>
  <tr>
    <td class='flag us'></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: That result is definitely what I'm after but it's too specific. I need to use all of the flags, not just the US flag. I see they're 23px high which helps.

Comment: Hmm, strangely, after fiddling about a bit and trying to work out what each part was doing, reducing it to just  height:28px !important;
 margin-top:-4px; seems to have done the trick.